# phpmyadmin 404 after install on Debian VM

Tags: debian, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin using apt-get on a VirtualBox running Debian.

I have uninstalled, reinstalled, added an Include to the apache2.conf, made symlinks, etc, etc.

I ran this :  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin` to make sure I had ticked apache. No effect.

I ran this :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

thinking I needed to do things manually, no change.

Also did an `aptitude purge phpmyadmin` and `aptitude install phpmyadmin` still nothing.

The only thing that has changed is normally I get a blank html page that says "File not found." If I comment out the Alias in the phpmyadmin.conf I get a normal 404 page. Aside from that, after trying everything I can think of or find nothing has changed.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I thought, I was overlooking something.

I should have mentioned that this is a Vagrant box that I didn't create. For some reason, the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf was set to a sub folder of a sub folder. Once I noticed that, the issue became much more clear. Doh!

I had one other issue  - when making a symlink for phpmyadmin into the sub/sub folder - on Windows 7, even as an admin, creating symlinks can trigger a  "Protocol error." There is information on handling that [here](http://www.ahtik.com/blog/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/)

I am self-answering in the hopes that the next person who skips over checking httpd.conf will find this useful.